# Moving from Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32bit Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my VM hosted on windows 7.  I have used this image for development purposes.  I wanted to used Docker but found that I must have 64 bit Ubuntu in order to install and use Docker.  I downloaded a 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 image to create another instance of a VM but I get error trying to mount that to the new VM.  Is there anyway that I can have two instance of Ubuntu on the same VM one 32 bit and one 64 bit?

Comment: You need set OS bit to 64 in VM config

Comment: I do select a 64 bit OS at the configuration stage. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want create VM for Docker only you can use 
[Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)